# Nginx .php scripts restriction in subfolder

Tags: nginx, php

I would like to deny external (from web) access to some PHP files related to MoxieManager.

Whole MoxieManager is in www/moxiemanager folder, where www is accessible from web.

Now I tried this

```
server {
listen 80;

root /site/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

client_max_body_size 32M;
# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name site.dev;

# Restrictions
location /moxiemanager/data {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}
location /moxiemanager/classes/(.+)\.php$ {
    deny all;
    return 404; 
}       

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}

#error_page 404 /404.html;

# Parse allowed PHP scripts
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

where restriction to /moxiemanager/data is working flawlessly -> I can't now read /moxiemanager/data/storage/some_file.json.
But scripts like /moxiemanager/classes/Autoloader.php can be executed even if there is a rule for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed just one thing: regexp locations override non-regexp ones. So, a proper statement would look like yours, with only a slight change:

`location ~* /moxiemanager/classes/(.+)\.php$ {
    deny all;
    return 404; 
}`